# Change time format in R (POSIXlt)

Tags: r, datetime

I have a 4x2 data frame where one of the columns contains DateTime stamps. The DateTime is in the following format: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. I need to format the DateTime as `POSIXlt`, and I do not want seconds to show. The code below formats as `POSIXlt`, but somehow seconds are still showing. How can I get rid of the seconds? Thank you very much.

```
DATS <- structure(list(DateTime = c("2016-04-25  23:59:00", "2016-04-25  23:58:00","2016-04-25  23:57:00", "2016-04-25  23:56:00"), Last = c(42.84,42.84, 42.85, 42.85)), .Names = c("DateTime", "Last"), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame") 
DATS$DateTime <- strptime(DATS$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#Output for DATS after running code
              DateTime  Last
1 2016-04-25  23:59:00 42.84
2 2016-04-25  23:58:00 42.84
3 2016-04-25  23:57:00 42.85
4 2016-04-25  23:56:00 42.85
```

Comment: Simple answer, you don't. If you want them as POSIXlt objects, that includes seconds.

Comment: You can use: format(DATS$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), but this will convert from POSIX to character.  Which is OK if you are only concern is the output appearance.

Comment: Gracos, are you asking how you display the data without showing seconds, or are you asking how you store the data without seconds? Subtle, but important difference. You could, for example, create an R class, and write a display function for the data that omits the seconds. Alternatively, you could simply use `sprintf()` to display the formatted output of the DATS structure.

Comment: Wanted POSIXlt format displayed without seconds. Did not know was not possible to get POSIXlt to not show the seconds. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other have answered, the seconds will need to be included. As an example, note if I remove ":%S" and change the seconds from 00 to various numbers, the seconds are still included but rounded down to 00.

```
    DATS <- structure(list(DateTime = c("2016-04-25  23:59:15", "2016-04-25  23:58:30","2016-04-25  23:57:45", "2016-04-25  23:56:59"), Last = c(42.84,42.84, 42.85, 42.85)), .Names = c("DateTime", "Last"), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
DATS$DateTime <- strptime(DATS$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
DATS
```

---

```
             DateTime  Last
1 2016-04-25 23:59:15 42.84
2 2016-04-25 23:58:30 42.84
3 2016-04-25 23:57:45 42.85
4 2016-04-25 23:56:59 42.85
```

---

```
DATS$DateTime <- strptime(DATS$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
DATS
```

---

```
             DateTime  Last
1 2016-04-25 23:59:00 42.84
2 2016-04-25 23:58:00 42.84
3 2016-04-25 23:57:00 42.85
4 2016-04-25 23:56:00 42.85
```